# Проблема с выводом данных MySQL в Python

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5

Нужно вывести просто элемент из таблицы, конкретно 8-13 Гц

```
k = "SELECT ansR FROM diplom.question WHERE idquest = 4;"
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(k)
                result = cursor.fetchone()
                print(result)
```

Но, кроме элемента, выводится еще и название столбца.
Выглядит это так

```
{'ansR': '8-13 Гц'}
```

Comment: `print(result['ansR'])`

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло))